# Use the Next Intl Link component within the markup function

Tags: next.js, next-intl

I was wondering if it is at all possible to pass the link component from the markup function or any other method within Next Intl.

Currently I can only find 2 options and neither seems optimal.

Option 1. Use multiple broken translations to create the required string with link inside
Option 2. Use the following markup where I simply use an a tag (This causes full refreshes of the page)

```
translations.markup("reset", {
link: (chunks) => `<a class="text-highlighted" href="/auth/reset-password">${chunks}</a>`,
})
```